# Kernel density estimation (KDE) for data points with different variance

Tags: kernel-smoothing

Consider the following situation: 
An experiment was done in 15 different conditions, and a value of the parameter 'A' was measured in each experiment (A can have any integer value between 0 and infinity). 3 repetitions were done in each condition, so that there are a total of 45 measurements of 'A'.

I want an estimate for the probability density function to measure a certain value of 'A'.

The first thing I tried was to average the 3 repetitions in each of the 15 different conditions, and do Kernel density estimation (KDE) over the 15 data points with a Gaussian kernel (I use a Matlab function that automatically chooses the optimal bandwidth for the kernel).

Then I realized that *in different conditions the variance between repetitions is different*, and I believe that this variance is important information that should be taken into account. The following plot shows this situation: the blue line is the KDE, and the points are the measurements of 'A' in each condition, averaged over 3 repetitions. The error bars indicate the standard deviation between the 3 repetitions in each condition (The hight of the points don't convey any information, they are just spread in the y axis so their error bars don't intersect).

[image]

I think this graph shows an example where the variance of each data point has important information that the KDE misses (I think there should be one small peak instead of two, considering the large variances of the points in the two smaller peaks).

My question: what is the best way to estimate the probability distribution function in this situation, taking into account the variance of each data point?

Solutions I considered:

1. should I choose different kernel bandwidth for each point, larger bandwidth for larger variance?
2. should I just do KDE on all 45 data points (15 conditions with 3 repetitions each)?
3. should I use a different method, other than KDE?

**Edit: I'm adding some details about the data:
This is gene expression data in bacteria (RNA-seq). If you know nothing about this, just know that gene expression is the how many of a certain type of molecule (that is related to a certain gene) are present in a population of bacteria. 
Each experiment starts with a small number of bacteria, that are then grown in one of 15 conditions (different PH levels, different nutrition etc). After the bacteria divide and grow to large numbers, we measure the gene expression in the population for every gene (the graph I'm showing is for one gene). For every condition we do 3 repetition, mean that 3 small groups of bacteria are grown separately in the same condition. 
Another consideration: the variation of gene expression between repetitions of the same condition is not expected to be Gaussian. We know that some genes in some conditions it's a Poisson distribution. For some it is not at all Poisson, and sadly for us the standard deviation is much larger than the mean. 
My objective was to find out if I can define sates of gene expression that can be considered "on" or "off". This is why I tried KDE.

I'm new to Kernel density estimation.

Comment: Why do you want to use KDE in here instead of mixture of Gaussians?

Comment: I don't want to assume the number of Gaussian in my data.... I want the estimation to tell me how many peaks are there in the probability density function... Even if I do use mixture of Gaussians, should I use it on all 45 data points, ignoring the fact that they actually came from 15 conditions?

Comment: OK, but this can be done by model selection.

Comment: @Tim is right about model selection. So perhaps you mean to ask: what is the best model selection method for 1D data in which we expect 10-20 Gaussians over a specifiable range of means [0-700] and a specifiable range of variances [10-1000]?

Comment: In my experience KDE is good for finding critical points: maxes, mins and inflection points. You can get those on one pass -- but only AFTER you've come up with a "suitable" bandwidth. The density profile itself from basic KDE has bias proportional to the second curvature of the density profile, so bias correction involves using KDE multiple times to estimate derivatives of densities. Once you go down the KDE hole, expect to be there for a while.

Comment: Lastly, the Epanechnikov kernel (parabolic form) is the most efficient kernel. I suggest you use that one for the density estimation, but there are other kernels that are better for higher derivative estimations. Suitable bandwidths are larger for the derivatives than for the original density. Bruce Hansen's unpublished Econometrics text is available for free online and has a detailed chapter on KDE. There is a lot to learn.

Comment: Could you tell us more about your data? What was measured? Why three repetitions? Why they differ? What are the 15 conditions? Isn't it a regression problem rather then density estimation?

Comment: Thanks for edit, but I wonder, if there are different conditions and different measurements, why do you want to model their distribution taken together..? It doesn't seem to make much sense. E.g. say that you had data with exam results from english, math and history, what would the distribution of the exam scores *together* mean? Aren't you rather interested in conditional distributions given the conditions?

Comment: Thank you for the comments, they made me realize that I left out some important information, please see my edit.

Comment: @Tim In your example of tests I would look at it like this: you take one student (or a bacteria species) and ask if his test scores on math, history, etc are distributed in a certain way: I want to know if there are certain subjects that where he gets really high score, and others where he gets low scores, and cluster them if possible.

Comment: In bacteria it's more obvious, for example: If you have lactose in your environment you would want to express the genes related to lactose metabolism. I want to know if there is an "off" state in certain conditions where the lactose related genes are not expressed or lowly expressed around a certain value,  and other conditions where the gene is highly expressed, where in these conditions the expression level would be around a certain high value.

Comment: OK, understood. Wouldn't it make sense to each condition has it's own distribution and then check if they overlap? So $i$-th sample from $j$-th condition is distributed as something like $y_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_j, \sigma_j)$?

Comment: yes it would because I believe that different conditions may have different stds and averages. But how do I proceed to guess the distribution across conditions?